# Combine two separate update queries into a single compound query

Tags: mysql

I have two separate update queries, i.e., "Update Query #1" & "Udpate Query #2". I would like to combine these two queries into a single compound query.

QUERY #1:
/*remove bad dates in [addr.stuupd]*/

```
UPDATE addr
   SET addr.STUUPD= NULL
 Where addr.STUUPD='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

QUERY #2:
/*remove bad dates in [loan.DDBTUPD] date field*/

```
UPDATE loan
   SET loan.DDBTUPD= NULL
 Where loan.DDBTUPD='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this -- I'd suggest keeping it 2 separate queries...

Comment: For what possible benefit?

Answer (score 1):

I have taken the liberty of assuming that the real problem here is to ensure that both tables are updated at the same time, and neither update fails.  In that case I would use a transaction.

Compound queries are normally only referred to with "select" statements.  Reliable handling of multiple updates is provided by "transactions" because they support rollback if one part of the update fails.

NB: transactions only work with InnoDB tables.

You can change your tables to InnoDB with

```
mysql> alter table `addr` engine = InnoDB
mysql> alter table `loan` engine = InnoDB
```

Before...

```
mysql> select * from loan ;
+--------+---------------------+
| loanid | DDBTUPD             |
+--------+---------------------+
|      1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
|      2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
|      3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
+--------+---------------------+
```

The transaction...

```
mysql> START TRANSACTION;  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE addr SET addr.STUUPD= NULL Where addr.STUUPD='0000-00-00 00:00:00' ;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> UPDATE loan SET loan.DDBTUPD= NULL Where loan.DDBTUPD='0000-00-00 00:00:00' ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

At this point, you will be able to see the results of the update, but other users will not

```
mysql> select * from loan ;
+--------+---------+
| loanid | DDBTUPD |
+--------+---------+
|      1 | NULL    | 
|      2 | NULL    | 
|      3 | NULL    | 
+--------+---------+
```

You will need to commit the transaction

```
mysql> COMMIT ; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

I suspect that peterm's solution below will run into problems if one of the tables does not have dates equal to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and the other table does.  peterm's query might not null out everything as expected.  I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's technically possible with a query like this

```
UPDATE addr a JOIN loan l 
    ON a.stuupd = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
   AND l.ddbtupd = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
   SET a.stuupd = NULL, 
       l.ddbtupd = NULL
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d0870/1)** demo

the question remains for what practical reason?

Comment: I'm not sure about MySQL, but it does not work on Oracle unless `a.stuppd` and `l.ddbtupd` have unique keys.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Take a look at sqlfiddle example that I provided with the answer

Comment: @user2803379 Did it help after all?